# Size of C++ types with different compilers

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang, clang++

I would like to avoid to fall into the [XY trap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so here is the original problem:

We have a small program which creates a shared memory segment on the PC. This program creates it by reading its structure from its header file (bunch of individual and nested struct definition). Basically just a .h and a .cpp file. This program will be compiled by g++.

We would like to create another program, a shared memory viewer, which displays the layout of this memory in a tree view. For that, we have to parse the previously mentioned header file and computing the offsets to read/manipulate the content of the specific part of the shared memory. We do not want to write a parser if it is not necessary especially because the header file contains additional declarations and definitions too. This program will be compiled by the same version of g++ as the previous program.

Originally, we wanted to use gccxml in the second program to parse the header file but it is based on 4.2 gcc and is cannot parse the included header files which contain C++11 code. Another idea is to use libclang to get the structure of that header file. libclang contains size information too, but I do not know if the size of the types and padding/alignment is the same in case of g++ and clang.

My question is: can you assume that the size of the C++ types and the padding/alignment of the structs will be the same when you compile the code with clang and g++? The environment (PC, OS) is the same. I am afraid we cannot, because the C++ standard does not specify the exact sizes of the types.

Do you know another solution to the original problem?

Comment: why not use the original compiler to create a small program that outputs the relevant data member offsets and sizes.

Comment: I don't even understand why you'd want to have another program - why not just have a command line switch for the "create" program to operate in a "print/manipulate the tree" mode?  If you insist on a second program - put the class definitions in the header (if they're not already there) and have the second program include it too.  Surely with the struct/class definitions,. it's not hard to reconnect to the shared memory segment and create struct/class pointers to interpret the memory content with...?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Since clang has as a goal to "be compatible with gcc" (for both C and C++), I would say that you can expect it to generate same offsets and sizes for the same code.

Long answer:
Assuming you are using only basic types (`int`, `short`, `double`, `char` and pointers to those types), and we're restricting to gcc and clang (and their C++ versions), keeping to the same OS and same bitness (32- or 64-bit on "both sides"), then subject to actual bugs in the compiler, it should have the same structure layout.

Of course, that is a long list of restrictions, and of course the "subject to actual bugs" is a never-ending concern in these cases.

You can make your case a bit easier if you use defined size types, such as `uint32_t` rather than `int` - conversely, if you put a class member in the structure, that has virtual members, you'd be seriously in trouble - but that doesn't work very well with shared memory anyway, as it's not guaranteed to be at the same place in different applications.

Be wary of STL functionality - you may not get the same C++ library for the two compilers (you may, or may not, depending on how you installed it).

I would double check, by adding some code to print the offset and size of important members (and run with both compilers, of course)  - don't forget to do this for the members deep inside some struct, since it could well be that the overall size of a struct could be identical and the content could be at different offsets.

(As others have said, I have seen projects where some code is generated with a script that prints the offsets of the struct members, and this is used as input for other programs in the project)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in this particular case, you should be fine.

The memory layout of data-structures is part of the ABI (Application Binary Interface), and gcc and clang both follow the [Itanium ABI](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) on x86 (and x86_64). Therefore, baring bugs, and provided they both compile for x86 or x86_64, they should end up with binary compatible types.

---

In the general case, you would typically cheat:

1. Use *packed* data structure: `struct X { ... } __attribute__((packed)) __attribute__((aligned (8)));` and you completely control the structure memory layout
2. As mentioned by Alf, have one compiler spew the offset of each member and use that to feed the generation of structures for the second compiler
3. Other ?

Comment: Note that using instances of any compiler-version dependent classes as member variables (like say, `std::string` or `std::list`) may change memory layout of the encapsulating struct. If you use basic types you should be fine though.

Comment: @rubenvb: Not really. 1/ Those are not compiler specific, Clang can perfectly compile libstdc++ and libc++ both; you are right it is important to use the same classes obviously. 2/ Be careful that `std::string` or `std::list` cannot be used "as is" in a shared-memory segment anyway, because they will point to memory local to a process; even overriding the allocator is not necessarily enough (it is if the segment is always mapped at the same address). Boost provides advanced types ([for this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html))

Answer (score 0):

Size of data types vary from platform to platform. Instead of hardcoding, use sizeof operator to find out appropriate size applicable for the target platform, for example,

```
sizeof(int)
sizeof(char)
sizeof(double)
```

etc.

Comment: The question is somewhat more detailed than that, if you read it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you use fixed width integer types (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) in a C-style struct and arrange members in decreasing order of size (i.e. largest members first), it should be pretty safe.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your issue. This is what Chrome does

```
COMPILE_ASSERT(sizeof(double) == 8, Double_size_not_8);
```

It assumes the sizes will match but checks just to make sure.

`COMPILE_ASSERT` is a macro. [You can find the definition here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/base/macros.h) but the short version is it's just what it says. An assert that happens at compile time.

If the sizes did not match then one way to deal with it is to define your header in bytes only. Instead of for example

```
struct SomeBinaryFileHeader {
   int version;
   int width;
   int height;
};
```

You might do this

```
struct SomeBinaryFileHeaderReadWriteVersion {
   uint_8 version_0;
   uint_8 version_1;
   uint_8 version_2;
   uint_8 version_3;
   uint_8 width_0;
   uint_8 width_1;
   uint_8 width_2;
   uint_8 width_3;
   uint_8 height_0;
   uint_8 height_1;
   uint_8 height_2;
   uint_8 height_3;
}
```

Etc. and then convert from one to the other which will even work across endianness

Comment: Note: in C++11 you do not need a macro for `static_assert` any longer, it's built in.

Comment: That's necessary the plan is to use this across multiple platforms, but shared memory is only available within a particular machine, so the code has to be compiled for that type of machine - meaning that byte-order and sizes of basic types are fixed (for a given bitness in the compiler, at least). So a tad excessive, I'd say.

Comment: That really depends. As someone who's been told. "One platform" and then a year later "please port this to these platforms" I'd prefer to be defensive and not have to find these kinds of issues after they've long been forgotten